# "as written by" vs. "written by"

Tags: meaning, grammar

- What is the meaning of "**as**" in "**as written by**"?

(I've searched every where like in many dictionaries or Googled it but there isn't the slightest sign on what that "**as**" exactly means and I thought no definition for "**as**" was proper in this situation.)

- Is " **written by**" a shortened form of "**as written by**", like it is always literally "**as written by**", but sometimes we shorten it in just "**written by**", what is the difference?
- which one is better to use in this sentence?

  > my prescription information pamphlets "**as written by**" my father (or just plain "**written by**" ... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrases

> written by
>   **as** written by
>   **which was** written by

all have the same meaning of saying who wrote *something* and are interchangeable.

The possible nuance of "as written by" draws attention to the fact that a particular person, who would usually be famous for having a different style from the usual, is doing the action.

> *Peter and the Wolf*, narrated by *somebody*
>   *Peter and the Wolf* as narrated by David Bowie